# Which IP address(es) should I use for Allowed Hosts in Elysia Cron?

Tags: cron

I am configuring [Elysia Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) on a Rackspace Managed Cloud Server. We have a loadbalancer in front of two webservers.

Am I supposed to use all three (3) IP addresses (Load Balancer, Web01, Web02) in the "Allowed Hosts" field (= a Drupal setting)? Or just use the IP address of the Load Balancer?

Comment: Are you sure this should be on Drupal Answers rather than Server Fault?

Comment: maybe you are right - just a drupal guy so I came here right away. Thanks.

Comment: You should use only 1 IP/domain to run cron tasks, else will it not get duplicated and adds to the load of server ? And what setting are you referring to btw ? Have you set up crontab entries ?

Comment: yes a crontab to fire off elysia_cron/cron.php thanks for your response.